# How to generate metamodel in Gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, eclipselink

I need to generate class meta models in Spring application. I added a task in [`build.gradle`](https://pastebin.com/KzBGbBWb) (this is my file code build.gradle), but this code does not work. It does not generate any files. There is no reaction. For the time being, I am doing [this](https://pastebin.com/ZyJL0nmM) manually, but I would like Gradle to do it automatically.

Comment: What is the output when you invoke `gradle generateMetaModel`? Also have a look here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html. You haven't specified `main` class for `JavaExec`.

Comment: Have you finally worked out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Too little details to help you effectively, however I see you didn't specify the `main` configuration argument for `JavaExec` which is required to make this task run correctly. If it's missing it should just finish with an exception. What is the gradle output in your case?